# ADO.NET request not returning data from all columns

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ado.net, sql-server-express

Working on a small project with VS2010 and SQLEXPRESS.

I have the following table with some data I entered:

[Table fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlU1w.png)

When I execute this:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString)) {
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ACCOUNTS", conn);

    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        while (reader.Read()) {
            accountList.Add(new Account((int)reader["id"], (float)reader["number"], (AccountType)reader["type"], (string)reader["name"], (float)reader["balance"], (float)reader["maxdebit"], (int)reader["userId"]));
        }//Not tested
    } // Dispose Reader

    //do something here
} // Dispose implicitly called
```

The debugger show me the following:

[Debugger output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoFIa.png)

He only gets the first 4 columns, for some reason. I've never seen this behavior before and the code to get it seems good. Anyone got any clues for me?

EDIT: Problem solved.

The problem turned out to be an InvalidCastingException. For some reason. The issue with only 4 items of the array showing up was not really a problem as it turns out. The FieldCount variable indicated 7 fields, which is exactly what's in the table. So those were all retrieved.

My table data looks like this:

Ik0Ap.png (add the imgur plz... no images and only 2 hyperlinks when under 10 reputation points. I edited to show this has been solved so it's me submitting... so I have this problem)

Maximum of 2 hyperlinks under 10 points...

It clearly says "float", so I did a cast to float. But according to the VS debugger, it's a double. So the casting was invalid. *sigh*

So that was the main problem. Why only 4 pieces of the array were shown is still a mystery to me... Maybe a VS2010 setting to prevent arrays with thousands of objects from being printed to the debugger?

Comment: err what does the debugger show for the other fields (userid and maxdebit)?

Comment: @Hogan: Nothing. And I don't mean NULL, I mean they're not there. In the debugger. These 4 are the only ones listed.

Comment: try `reader[4]` and `reader[5]` - that work better?

Comment: @Hogan: not really. Oddly enough, Fieldcount indicates 7, which is indeed howmany there are. I tried changing the code to expect objects only, that worked. Now I'm dealing with casting exceptions.

Comment: You should be able to look at the object in the debugger and see the type. (It will be on the right hand in the watch or inspector window.)

Comment: @Hogan: yeah, I didn't see that. Was a big help. I fixed everything now, I'll edit to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the columns explicitly, as in:

```
SELECT id, name, number, type, balance, ... etc.
```

Comment: @Robert_Harvey: Tried it, same result. First 4 columns and then nothing. I don't get it...

Comment: Is `ACCOUNTS` a view, rather than a table?  Does `connString` point to the correct database?

Comment: @Robert_Harvery: `ACCOUNTS` is indeed a table, not a view. The connString I copied from the server explorer, so that should be good.

Comment: It gives you all of the columns in the Server Explorer?  How about SQL Server Management Studio Express?  Does that also return all columns?

Comment: @Robert_Harvey: Yes, I have it installed. Gives all columns.